# How to get XML response on Guzzle

Tags: php, xml, https, guzzle

I've been trying to parse the text that the body returns into XML (should return it in XML) but so far It just returns it like text.
Here's the code and what should look like.

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $options = [
        'headers' => ['Accept'=>'application/xml'],
        'auth' => ['Deversor-Channel', '?1_sIWVZ((ujV)kDBM!6O5!AFAQM*K*yr(?E.(g='],
        'body' => "<request>
                        <hotel_id>345786
                        </hotel_id>
                        <last_change>2021-07-19</last_change>
                    </request>",
    ];
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://secure-supply-xml.booking.com/hotels/xml/reservations', $options);
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    // "200"
    echo $res->getBody();
    // {"type":"User"...'
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody(),'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    echo $xml;
```

[This is how it should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM8tJ.png)

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqgWN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The echo you're doing right now will trigger the `__toString()` method of the SimpleXMLElement you created using `simplexml_load_string()`, which is essentially the string content of that object.

What you're looking for is `$xml->asXML()`, which will output a well-formed XML string. You might also need to add a `Content-Type` header for some browsers to pick up the XML content. Try the following:

```php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
    use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
    use GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $options = [
        'headers' => ['Accept'=>'application/xml'],
        'auth' => ['Deversor-Channel', '?1_sIWVZ((ujV)kDBM!6O5!AFAQM*K*yr(?E.(g='],
        'body' => "<request>
                        <hotel_id>345786
                        </hotel_id>
                        <last_change>2021-07-19</last_change>
                    </request>",
    ];
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://secure-supply-xml.booking.com/hotels/xml/reservations', $options);
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    // "200"
    echo $res->getBody();
    // {"type":"User"...'
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody(),'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Oh I see! It works now, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that! If my answer solved your problem, kindly [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark next to it.